# Trying to store a table and have it load after refresh?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, tablerow

I am taking information from a form, and storing it as an object into an array.
then I am stringifying that, and storing it into local storage.
grabbing it from local storage,
and attempting to have the row show up. 
its a "to do list" web app.

I want it to save the tasks, so that they are there when i come back/refresh the page. but everytime I refresh the page, it just disappears. It looks like the information is still stored in the local storage after I refresh, though. so that isn't the issue. However, if I refresh, AND THEN add a new task, it wipes the storage so that only the new tasks in that session are added.

how can I get this to wear I can add a task, and then, save everything, and have everything STAY even after I refresh?

I tried calling the buildTable function at the top of my file, thinking it might build the table so its there for me when I load the page, but it isn't working.

Thanks!

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableBody");


var toDoArray = [];
buildTable();

function buildTable(){

var retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("task");
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);
var addTheTaskName = parsedObject.taskName;
var addTheTaskDate = parsedObject.taskDate;

for(i=0; i < toDoArray.length; i++){
  addTaskToTable(parsedObject[i]);
}



}

function addTaskToTable(obj){
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellDate = row.insertCell(1);
  var cellId = row.insertCell(2);
  var cellCheck = row.insertCell(3);
  cellName.innerHTML= obj.name;
  cellDate.innerHTML= obj.date;
  var checkStuff = "<input type='checkbox'>";
  cellCheck.innerHTML = checkStuff;

}

function submitForm(name,date) {
    var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
    var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
    var taskSomething = getTaskObj(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
      toDoArray.push(taskSomething);
      addTaskToTable(taskSomething);
      var storedArray = JSON.stringify(toDoArray);
      localStorage.setItem("task",storedArray);
};

function getTaskObj(taskName,taskData){
var taskObject = {
        name: taskName,
        date: taskData,
      };
 return taskObject;
}
```

Comment: add design or create fiddle so that it will be easily understandable

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ptzkLqc4/ ... tried to make a fiddle but it didnt really work right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i've fix your fillde to work >> https://jsfiddle.net/ptzkLqc4/1/

```
function buildTable() {
  var retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("task");
  var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);
  for (i = 0; i < parsedObject.length; i++) {
      toDoArray.push(getTaskObj(parsedObject[i].name, parsedObject[i].date));
      addTaskToTable(parsedObject[i]);
  }
}
```

---

basicly, since you overwriting your localStorage by toDoArray values, you need to fill toDoArray with localStorage value on load.